# Filter rows in a table with the gap between the values SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to filter rows of a table based on the gap between the dates.
Let me explain, I has a table sorted by EMETTEUR AND DATE like this:

```
EMETTEUR |   DATE
----------------------------
E1       |  13/06/2015 10:01
E1       |  13/06/2015 10:30
E1       |  13/06/2015 16:01
E1       |  13/06/2015 17:01
E2       |  14/06/2015 08:01
E2       |  15/06/2015 14:01
E3       |  15/06/2015 09:01
E3       |  15/06/2015 15:01
E3       |  15/06/2015 22:23
E4       |  12/06/2015 12:01
E4       |  12/06/2015 14:11
E4       |  12/06/2015 14:22
E5       |  15/06/2015 13:01
E5       |  15/06/2015 14:13
E6       |  11/06/2015 19:01
```

I am trying to select unique rows where the gap is greater than 5h, as you see in this picture

```
EMETTEUR |   DATE
----------------------------
E1       |  13/06/2015 10:30
E1       |  13/06/2015 17:01
E2       |  14/06/2015 08:01
E2       |  15/06/2015 14:01
E3       |  15/06/2015 09:01
E3       |  15/06/2015 15:01
E3       |  15/06/2015 22:23
E4       |  12/06/2015 14:22
E5       |  15/06/2015 14:13
E6       |  11/06/2015 19:01
```

FOR EMETTEUR E1 we have 4 rows, we selected rows 2 and 4 beacause the gap is greater than 5.

to solve this problem I thought had set up another table TMP resort where I inserted line by line and achque time I check to an issuer, the date difference between the line and insert the line in the destination table is lower has 5 hours so I do a update or I insert the line.

This solution is too long because the data that I will exceed filter 3000000 Online

Answer (score 0):

You can express the query using `lag()`, but unfortunately, that is not available in SQL Server 2008.

The following query does what you want:

```
select t.*
from table t cross apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table t2
      where t2.emetteur = t.emetteur and
            t2.date < t.date
     ) tprev
where t.date > dateadd(hour, 5, tprev.date);
```

For performance, the best index is on `(emetteur, date)`.

However, if you need performance for this type of query, you might need to store the previous/next value in the records (using a trigger/stored procedure on inserts).  Or, you might consider upgrading to SQL Server 2012/2014, which support `lag()` and which should be a bit more optimized.

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(date) over (partition by emetteur order bydate) as prev_date
      from table t 
     ) t
where t.date > dateadd(hour, 5, prev_date);
```